# URL - send current location via SMS keep return 0,0 in latitude and longitude - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, location, sms

I am trying to get longitude and latitude and send it via SMS to saved contact. But the longitude and latitude return 0,0 in my URL.
How can I fix that? I tried some solution that I found here but it doesn't work for me.

This is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // check for runtime permissions
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 100);
        }
    }

    // this is a special permission required only by devices using
    // Android Q and above. The Access Background Permission is responsible
    // for populating the dialog with "ALLOW ALL THE TIME" option
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, 100);
    }



    button1 = findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    db = new DbHelper(this);
    list = db.getAllContacts();
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, list);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    send = findViewById(R.id.send);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // calling of getContacts()
            if (db.count() != 5) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can't Add more than 5 Contacts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Location object = new Location("service Provider");
            double lat = object.getLatitude(); double lng = object.getLongitude();
            onSuccess(object);
        }
    });

}

public void onSuccess(Location currentLocation) {

    String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + currentLocation.getLatitude()+","+currentLocation.getLongitude();
    StringBuffer smsBody = new StringBuffer();
    smsBody.append(Uri.parse(uri));
        // get the SMSManager
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        // get the list of all the contacts in Database
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(MainActivity.this);
        List<ContactModel> list = db.getAllContacts();

        // send SMS to each contact
        for (ContactModel c : list) {
            String message = "Hey, " + c.getName() + "I am in DANGER, i need help. Please urgently reach me out. Here are my coordinates.\n " + uri;
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(c.getPhoneNo(), null, message, null, null);
        }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions Denied!\n Can't use the App!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // get the contact from the PhoneBook of device
    switch (requestCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String hasPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                    String phone = null;
                    try {
                        if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
                            phones.moveToFirst();
                            phone = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                        }
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        db.addcontact(new ContactModel(0, name, phone));
                        list = db.getAllContacts();
                        customAdapter.refresh(list);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

And I am using Oreo version for Android. And for manifest: SEND_SMS , INTERNET , ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION , ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION , READ_CONTACTS.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Cant you determine lat,lon? Or cant you send them? Or cant you receive them?

Comment: `keep return 0,0 in latitude and longitude ` Whic function are you calling that returns 0,0?

Comment: `But the longitude and latitude return 0,0 in my URL. ` Sooy, but i do not understand that sentence.

Comment: my app is about sending an sms with an url (with longitude and latitude). I call the methode `onSuccess` . The sms sent but the logitude and latitude are 0. This the url that has sent : **http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=0.0,0.0**

Comment: `smsBody.append(Uri.parse(uri));` Why mess around with Uri? Better: `smsBody.append(uri);` And sorry uri is no uri but an url.

Comment: i did that but it's still the same.

Comment: So you send `saddr=0.0,0.0 `. Why? Also i had three questions in my first comment. You could answer them one by one as now i dont know what's happening.

Comment: the ptoblem is i don't get my current location (lon and lat)

Comment: yes i cant dtermine lat and lon it keep give 0 in lat and lon

Comment: Well then why talking abouty sending an sms? You will not send an sms if you cannot get your location we think. So change your post. Remove the snms stuff and tell your app cannot determine location. As it is now you blame the sms thing. Very confusing.

Comment: When i sent SMS this is the URL that i get :  maps.google.com/maps?saddr=0.0,0.0

Comment: i should get the current lon and lat in my URL but instead i get 0.0 , 0.0

Comment: If you get 0.0,0.0 then you sent 0.0,0.0. Check for null's before sending an sms.

Comment: how i can sheck for null's

Comment: if ( currentLocation.getLatitude() == 0) ...

Comment: `double lat = object.getLatitude(); double lng = object.getLongitude();` You are not using those values. After that you call onSuccess() where you use other variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an instance of `Location` yourself:

```java
Location object = new Location("service Provider");
```

That will have a location of 0,0 because you did not tell it where the location is.

If you are expecting to actually get the device location, you cannot create the instance of `Location` yourself, as you are doing. You need to [use `LocationManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager) to obtain the `Location`.